# Powershell ISE code completion

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I like that I can see what I can use when pressing `ctrl + space` in Powershell ISE. How could I see the suggestions for all the functions.

example:

- let's assign a date to a variable
- `$a = get-date`

Now, if I want to see the type of the variable, I can write:

- `$a.GetType()`

As soon as I hit that dot above, I can see `getType` in the menu. 
All good so far, but if I want the full name, I can use:

- `$a.GetType().FullName`

*What **I would want is***, a dropdown menu with suggestions for `.FullName` too. I found that I can use `FullName` by mistake but , I had no idea I could have done that.

Is there a way to enable this?
Thank you!

ps: Sorry if this a beginner's question, but it would make my life easier, if possible.

edit: here's what i see:

[image]

Comment: In my ISE 3.0 works as you want. And  I have no particular setup or configuraion. After the `$a.GetType().` dropdown menu is opened!

Comment: Also running ISE 3.0 on Windows 10, works fine for me too. So when you press Ctrl+Space after `$a.FullName.` you don't get anything?

Comment: I have ISE 3.0 on windows 7 and I don't get anything

Comment: please see my edit. Maybe this `missing property name after reference operator` will ring any bells (Used another variable `b` in the same way as described in the question)

Comment: I have ISE 4.0 on windows 8.1 and [Intellisense](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/12/intellisense-in-windows-powershell-ise-3-0/) brings drop-down automatically after typing last dot in `$a.GetType().` **only in _Script pane_** but does not in _Console pane_.  However, Intellisense brings drop-down in `$b.`, where `$b=$a.GetType()` in _Console pane_ as well.

Comment: @josefZ Yes only in script pane works. I'm on ISE 3.0 on windows 7

Comment: thank you for trying this out for me. Is there anything I could do? Note: install or upgrade the shell are not among my options. Only to try to modify files/settings.

Comment: @JosefZ I just tried your way. It it shown indeed in the script panel. Is there a way to also display it in the console panel?

Comment: Both `(get-date).GetType().` as well as `$a = get-date;$a.GetType().` bring drop-down immediately after typing concluding dot even in _Console pane_… Not found any way to persuade Intellisense behaviour in _Console pane_ the same as in _Script pane_, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is neither configuration, nor any other thing that you can do to change this behaviour:

- In Script pane, you have the desired functionality.
- In Console pane, you have to assign the result of the `$a.GetType()` into a variable like `$b= $a.GetType()`, and then type `$b.` to indirectly get the desired Intellisense for `$a.getType()`

Disclaimer: this all is included in the comments, but I think it deserves to appear in an answer, so that other people can find it.